# Adobe AIR app works fine on ADL but crashes when run separately

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I am developing an app for Adobe AIR. The app works fine on Adobe Flash CC when I run it through the ADL. When I publish the app for Desktop and run it, I get the following error: 
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.filesystem::File could not be found.

This is strange, because it seems that actually, when I run the app outside Adobe Flash, the app is run through Flash Player.

The code that causes the problem is this:

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;

function saveData(): void {
    var pathToFile: String = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('test.txt').nativePath;
    var someFile: File = new File(pathToFile);
    var stream: FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(someFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTFBytes(csv);
    stream.close();
}
```

It crashes on

```
var pathToFile: String = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('test.txt').nativePath;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What Player do you have specified in File > Publish Settings?

Comment: It's AIR 15.0.0.249 for Desktop. ActionScript 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You must publish Adobe AIR Application and not just "SWF" file.

Message:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.filesystem::File could not be found.
```

mean that your SWF was executed not from AIR but from simple Flash Player.

You must setup Target AIR for desktop (also download latest AIR SDK) like this:

[image]

Also you can select ways of distribution of your Application:

[image]

I suggest to use "Application with runtime embedded" because in this case you will receive App with all runtime included and your users will not receive any inconvenience with your software.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. I publish the app either as AIR package or with the runtime embedded. When I open the app, it crashes when trying to access the File class, as if it's not being run by Adobe AIR. I don't have this behaviour when I build it through Flash.

Comment: No, if I export as suggested with an application.app, I double click on this file and it runs the application. I don't enter the package to open the SWF. However, even if I open the .app file, still I have the same problem

Comment: Please provide your OS version

Comment: Mac OSX 10.9.4 and the Adobe AIR SDK is 15.0.0.249

Comment: Could you please send me compiled sample to http://gamespoweredby.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/mymail.jpg this email? (open image - there is email)